# Manipulating a list by dividing a number with all predecessors

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

Setup: python 3.6

I want to create list and filter the list by math rules in order to find the prime number.

Part 1: Function for assign the square root of each number

Part 2: Create the list and just add the numbers with an root %1 != 0.

Part 3: The issue: Calculate for each value whether its a prime number or not.

How to do the Part 3:
Take every number and divide the number with all prime numbers that are predecessors. A number is a prime number as long as it is NOT %1 == 0. 
And than go further to the next number at the list.

I really want to do it in that way in order to learn more about the way to handle the lists.

The result is just a very small list at the end.

```
y = int(input("Please put the last number you want to now: \n"))
x = 1 #  0 is not valid by logic and 1 is not valid by definition
prims = []

# Part 1: Function: Calculate the square root (1)
def rootV(i):
    return math.sqrt(i)


# Part 2: Set the range of numbers and create the first list
for j in range(x, y):
j = int(j + 1)
c = rootV(j)

if c %1 == 0:
    continue
else:
    prims.append(j) # Liste der Wert gegeben
    print(prims)

# Part 3: Analyse every value by division with his predesessors
for i in prims:
    if len(prims) == 1:
    print("Very short list my friend: " + str(i))
    elif len(prims) > 1:
       for number in prims:
            lastNumber = len(prims) - 1
            firstNumber = 0
            value = prims[lastNumber] / prims[firstNumber]
            if value %1 == 0:
                prims.remove(lastNumber)
                continue
            else:
                continue

print(prims)
```

Comment: You have missed a tab after the first if
"if len(prims) == 1:" , the print should tabbed.

Comment: Also there is some problem in logic , why would you check if the len of your list is equals one , after you already entered a for loop (at part 3) . check it first of all , to save run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the issues I see with your code:

- The removal of squares in the first two steps is unnecessary, a good
  prime finding algorithm will sort them out regardless.
- You should limit your divisor test to divisors whose square is less
  than (or equal to) the number being tested.  Rather than repeatedly compute
  squares, we can do that once in the first step, producing a list of
  numbers and their squares.
- You modify the list you're looping over which is dangerous. 
  It's safer if we make the outer loop walk a copy of the list and let
  the inner loop modify the original list only when it ends the loop.

Here's my simplified solution:

```
x, y = 1, 100

# Create list of numbers and their squares but numbers without an integer square root
pairs = [(j, j * j) for j in range(x + 1, y + 1)] # if (j ** 0.5) % 1 != 0]

# Calculate for each value whether its a prime number or not
for pair in list(pairs):  # walk over a *copy* of the pairs
    number, _ = pair

    # analyze every number by division with its predecessors
    for divisor, square in pairs:  # walk over the *original* pairs

        if square > number:  # finished testing
            break

        if number % divisor == 0:  # not a prime
            pairs.remove(pair)
            break

print(*(prime for prime, _ in pairs))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
>
```

You'll note that if you drop `if (j ** 0.5) % 1 != 0` at the end of the comprehension, allowing squares through, it makes no difference to the result as the prime testing logic detects them.

You'll further note that if you change the outer loop from `for pair in list(pairs):` to simply `for pair in pairs:` it breaks down and returns odd numbers as modifying the list on the inner loop affects the outer.

Comment: I learned a lot from your example. There comes a question to me I can't find out how the influence of _ = pair within the pair is.  `number` is easy to understand but why is the square called _ = pair? `number, _ = pair`

Comment: @foriinlist, the underscore (_) substitutes for a variable when we don't actually need that variable's value.  `number, _ = pair` means `pair` contains two things, I only need the first one.  Can also be written `number = pair[0]` in this situation, but not in this one:  `for prime, _ in pairs`.